# How to assign boolean int to Switch Button

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

I'm aware of SQLite has no Boolean and I'm using int of 0 and 1 as to determine true or false. Question is how do I assign the value I got from DB and assign it to a switch button? I'm not really understand how does the SimpleCursorAdapter parameters is organizing the layout. R.id.active is supposed to be my Switch button.

My files:

[image: My app's files]

My main class:

```
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    // The desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[] {
            AlarmDbAdapter.KEY_TIME,
            AlarmDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE,
            AlarmDbAdapter.KEY_ACTIVE,
    };

    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[] {
            R.id.time,
            R.id.alarmtitle,
            R.id.active,
    };

    // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
    //as well as the layout information
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, R.layout.alarmcomponent_layout,
            cursor,
            columns,
            to,
            0);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

fetching method in Adapter class

```
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {"rowid _id", KEY_TIME, KEY_TITLE, KEY_ACTIVE},
            null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

activity_lazino.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Lazino">

<ListView android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

alarmcomponent_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Time Here" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/alarmtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/time"
    android:text="Title Here"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activeText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Active?"
    android:layout_below="@+id/time"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/active"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/active" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/active"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use `SimpleCursorAdapter` to provide this functionality:

> An easy adapter to map columns from a cursor to TextViews or ImageViews defined in an XML file.

However, what you can do is hook your own [`SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html) to hook up the switch based on the boolean value.

Here's a quick example:

```
private SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder mViewBinder = new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        boolean  ret = false;

        //  Only handle the boolean Switch
        //  Rather than use a fixed number here, consider
        //  using a named constant which matches your column table.
        if (columnIndex == 2) {
            Switch btn = (Switch)view;
            if (cursor.getInt(columnIndex) == 0) {
                btn.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                btn.setChecked(true);
            }

            ret = true;
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that extract .. Cleared most of my mist but do you mind to help me hooking up my codes with the ViewBinder as an example for understanding?

Comment: It's weird that I actually wrote similar method but I kept getting NullPointerException on "btn.setChecked(false);". Even with your example, I got the same error when trying to setcheck the Switch button

Comment: Double check that the ID you are specifying in the table is actually in the layout you are providing.  You could also check the ID of the provided `View` and make sure that it is the one corresponding to the column.

Comment: actually it's nothing wrong with the ID but it has something to do with getParent() and I don't know why.. But I have posted up my answer which is worked for me

Comment: Something is definitely off there.  That step should not have been necessary.  If the arrays sent to the `SimpleCursorAdapter` specifying the view IDs and columns are correct and match the layout, the `findViewById()` should be giving you the same `View` as is passed in to the bind call.  I'd suggest updating your question with the layout file contents as well as the logcat output from the NPE you were seeing.

Comment: added layout files and regarding the logcat, it only pointed out the NPE on the .setCheck section

Comment: It may be because you have more than just the 3 IDs in your layout, though I admit that would be odd if it were the case.  What you might try instead is  doing a check on the `View` ID and if it is `R.id.active` then pull the boolean value from the `Cursor`.

Answer (score 0):

Quite absurd by the way I found the solution for this and I don't know why does it required for the view.getParent(); but this worked like a charm.

Any explanation why getParent() was required?

```
dataAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            View viewParent = (View) view.getParent();
            Switch switchbtn = (Switch) viewParent.findViewById(R.id.active);

            if(cursor.getString(3).equals("1") && !switchbtn.isChecked()) {
                switchbtn.setChecked(true);

                String text = (String)cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                ((TextView) view).setText(text);

                //Just for more understanding on how the columnIndex hops
                Log.wtf(null, "columnIndex: " + String.valueOf(columnIndex));
                return true;
            }else
                return false;
        }
    });
```